# Hacking Uploadify integration with Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, uploadify

I am using Uploadify with [Uploadify Integration Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/uploadify-integration/), all uploaded files goes to: `wp-content/uploads/year/month/`. How can I hack / improve the plugin to make possible that the files will be stored in a path that has the name of logged in user so I can distinguish who have uploaded them?

Or alternatively is possible to dynamically add a prefix with the username of logged in user?

I read [the discussion from this link](http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/7699/add-a-prefix-to-the-uploaded-file-name/p1) and according to Wordpress codex I can get the Wordpress username with this function:

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login ?>
```

But I don't know how to modify the plugin and implement that.

Naturally I already contacted the author of the plugin and asked but still no replies.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it might get you pretty far:

```
function user_upload_path($path = null) {

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $user_path = sanitize_file_name($current_user->user_login);

    return sprintf('%s/uploads/%s', WP_CONTENT_DIR, $user_path);

}
add_filter('pre_option_upload_path', 'user_upload_path');

function user_upload_url_path($path = null) {

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $user_path = sanitize_file_name($current_user->user_login);

    return sprintf('%s/uploads/%s', WP_CONTENT_URL, $user_path);

}
add_filter('pre_option_upload_url_path', 'user_upload_url_path');
```

I solved this by adding filters to `pre_option_upload_path` and `pre_option_upload_url_path` thus adding the username at the end of the path and url.

It's untested so far that I have not tried uploading. I did confirm that `wp_content_url()` will return both the path and url containing the username. I decided to put the user name before the date since that's the easiest thing to accomplish, but I get you can accomplish the opposite with a `user_upload_dir` filter and some regex.

Comment: Decided to try an upload, and that seems to be working out fine to. And, on a side note: I used `pre_option_%s` filters in order to avoid the values being overridden by WordPress or other plugins. If you would in fact like some customizability, use the `option_%s` equivalents instead.

Comment: You might also want to `update_post_meta` every time a file is uploaded and store the username of the user performing the upload. While my upload completed, was correctly stored and can be inserted into posts the file url will be wrong if another user is viewing it in the admin panel, e.g. media section. Perhaps you could use different filters for uploading and viewing files.